# Need to setup a Ruby on Rails App stack using docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, passenger

I have setup a Rails app on a docker container and a Apache web server on another container. I need the Apache web server to access the rails app for every request. The issue is I have to configure and compile phusion passenger which links the Rails app to the Apache binary. The file system path in container 1(rails app) should be configured in the Apache web config file in container 2. Is this possible ? How can I solve this problem.

Comment: You need to mount rails code(Host) as volume both to container 1 and container 2, or you can use app server(such as puma) and reverse proxy

Comment: But we are planning to set this up for production also so I think puma is not a good option. Can I create a volume in container 2 and mount it on container 1 and compile the phusion passenger ?

Comment: Follow the guide in passenger's github site https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker